# playframework 2.0 VirtualFile fromRelativePath is missing

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

In play 1.x was possible to use code that can get a file from relative application's path. Like this:

```
static File xmlDataFile= VirtualFile.fromRelativePath(
            "/app/parsers/data/some_data.xml"
    ).getRealFile();
```

This code is not controller's code. But some code in app/parsers package.

How can I do the this in playframework 2.x? For Java!

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003922/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-read-a-text-file-on-server-as-string-in-play-framewor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Result menu() throws IOException {

    String path = Play.application().resource("/resources/menu.json").toString();

    String content = Files.toString(new File(path), Charsets.UTF_8);

    return ok(content).as("JSON");
}
```