# What is the easiest way to read a text file on server as string in play framework 2.0

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I can't find VFS or any other simple straightforward way to read a text file as string in Play 2.0.4.

EDIT: I am looking for a java solution. sorry to miss that piece of info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
String content = Files.toString(new File("files/config.txt"), Charsets.UTF_8);
```

It is using Google Commons, included in Play by default.

Comment: just got this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614393/play-2-4-can-not-see-file-by-play-application-resource

Answer (score 1):

Play 2 imports Google Commons libraries by default, using it and Java's `File`, you can read any file and pass its stream to any place. No need for VFS anymore...

Comment: You can even import Apache commons making it much easier : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Answer (score 1):

When you are in Windows, don't forget to add the two '\' when passing the file path. 
For example:

```
    File file = new File(""); // to create an empty file 
    // we suppose that the file in the public folder 
    File file_to_read = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "\\public\\filename.txt");
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for Java or Scala solution?

In Scala you can do it this way (without external dependencies) to read from file

`scala.io.Source.fromFile("/path/to/file.txt").getLines`

or from Play resource

`scala.io.Source.fromURL(Play.resource("/resource/file/packaged/with/play.txt").get).getLines`