# Play 2.2.3 can not see file by Play.application().resource

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

Play 2.2.3. Windows 7.

```
public static Result menu() throws IOException {

    String path = Play.application().resource("resources/menu.json").toString();

    String content = Files.toString(new File(path), Charsets.UTF_8);

    return ok(content).as("JSON");
}
```

Got an error:

> ... scala-2.10\classes\resources\menu.json The filename, directory
>   name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Checking that path in file-system, I'm able to find my file there:

```
..\target\scala-2.10\classes\resources\menu.json
```

I'm able to find it there. Why play can't?

--

**UPDATE:** 
I've just figured out I can not create files on C:\ root folder on my machine. That maybe the issue. But on other hand I'm not accessing root folder, and ad trying to get read only access. And I do have write access to that file on that path anyway.

Comment: There is no Play 2.4.

Comment: Well. Last version then. 2.2.3. Will fix it. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

As actually you want to use your `menu.json` file as a static asset you can put it i.e. into `public/resources/menu.json` file and then read it with simple:

```
<script>
    $.get('@routes.Assets.at("resources/menu.json")');
</script>
```

or just directly by request:

```
http://localhost:9000/assets/resources/menu.json
```

To do what you want via controller you need to read the InputStream by **classpath** (remember that finally it will be archived into **jar** file!) but it need to be placed in `conf` folder i.e.: `conf/resources/menu.json` then from controller:

```
public static Result menuViaControllerJson() {
    InputStream is = Play.application().classloader().getResourceAsStream("resources/menu.json");
    return (is != null)
            ? ok(is)
            : notFound();
}
```

Anyway you will get exactly the same result as for common `Assets.at`, so consider if it's worth of effort.

**Edit:** If you want to use this file as custom config just use [HOCON syntax](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Configuration) file i.e.: `conf/ses.conf`:

```
foo = "bar"
```

and in controller:

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

....

Config cfg = ConfigFactory.parseResources(Play.application().classloader(), "ses.conf");
debug("My 'foo' is configured as: " + cfg.getString("foo"));
```

Comment: I would treat that json as configuration file that lives in my class-path.

Comment: In such case ... read it as a configuration file and use its HOCON syntax instead parsing JSON yourself ;)